# Finish activity so counters reset

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a game with score counters, round counters, etc, but what I find is that when I finish the game activity with the `finish()` method, the `ints` still have the same numbers as before, is there a way to get things to no longer persist in memory when the activity has been closed w/o force closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a game with score counters, round counters, etc, but what I find is that when I finish the game activity with the finish() method, the ints still have the same numbers as before

Then you are storing the information somewhere that lives past the life of an activity, such as a static data member.

Comment: oi. you're killer. it didn't even occur to me cause I didn't import those fields to any other classes, I just left them as static. what you said totally works. great book btw, perhaps i should finish reading it :|